# Creating a new interface in iOS App xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Good morning,

I'm trying to create a new interface for implementing a Page View Controller but I'm doing something wrong because it's not working. I hope someone can see the error and help me with that because I'm a little bit stuck on this problem.

http://autograpp.com/Main.jpg

aupViewController.m

```
#import "aupViewController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "SBJson.h"

@interface TutorialViewController ()

@end

@implementation TutorialViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Create the data model
    _pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
    _pageImages = @[@"page1.png", @"page2.png", @"page3.png", @"page4.png"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)startWalkthrough:(id)sender {
    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}

@end
```

aupViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "PageContentViewController.h"


@interface TutorialViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

- (IBAction)startWalkthrough:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageTitles;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageImages;

@end


@interface aupViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;


@end


@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtMail;

- (IBAction)registerClicked:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;

@end



@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

PageContentViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PageContentViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;

@property NSUInteger pageIndex;

@property NSString *titleText;

@property NSString *imageFile;

@end
```

PageContentViewController.m

```
#import "PageContentViewController.h"

@interface PageContentViewController ()

@end

@implementation PageContentViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageFile];
    self.titleLabel.text = self.titleText;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

But I'm getting the error:

**Cannot find interface declaration for TutorialViewController, did you mean LoginViewController?**

And why is this not working? I really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't imported the header file?

Comment: I have edited the first post with the headers. Thanks trojanfoe.

Comment: So what code is referencing this view controller?  Have you imported the header into *that* implementation file?

Comment: I have the Page View Controller done in an another project (made step by step from an another web) and at the moment is working fine, but when I try to implement it (copy and paste) in my project is not working in that new interface creation. Question: I have to créate a file called TurorialViewController?

Comment: No, the file name does not *have* to match the name of the class within it, although it's conventional to do so.  I think your error is simply a lack of import somewhere, but your answer does not reveal *where*.  You will have to update it with more detail.

Comment: and how is this "different project" connected to the above code?  Are you importing the projects into an Xcode workspace (you do understand that projects can only "see" files within the same project or within a dependent project, right?).

Comment: I'm going to update the first post with more code and files. I hope you can find something. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Done, I have put the full .h file and also the PageContentViewController.h and PageContentViewController.m files. I hope you find something. Thanks.

Comment: So what file is causing the compiler error?

Comment: The aupViewController.m file. I'm going to upload an screenshot of my storyboard if that helps you. Thanks again.

Comment: Done, if you need something more please tell me because the error keeps happenning.

Comment: Any update on that? Everything seems to be fine, right?

Comment: Yeah I cannot see why it's happening.

Comment: When I click the TutorialViewController interface is showing a different AupViewController.h file instead of my project's file. How can I change the 'URL' of this interface? Why is it changed? Thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like you have a messed-up Xcode project or Xcode workspace with multiple projects which are not correctly set-up.  I doubt anyone can really help you due to the complexity involved and the lack of visibility of the project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I had the wrong path in one of my files. I correct it and now everything is working. Thanks for your help.